# Apache Directory Studio cgi how to make it run on lubuntu?

Tags: apache2, lubuntu

I am trying to make Apache Directory Studio run on lubuntu... [directory.apache.org/studio/](http://directory.apache.org/studio/)

Some time ago I just download it unpaket it and run it... all in ubuntu 8.10.

But now how can I do this?

If I double click on th e file nothing happens.
[image]

[image]

in english " ApacheDirectoryStudio: can't execute the binary file"

Comment: did you remember to give it execute rights i.e. `chmod +x ~/bin/ADS/ApacheDirectoryStudio.xpm` ?

Comment: yeah I did that...

Comment: which java jre are you running - oracle or icedtea?

Comment: ok @fossfreedom I switched now from IcedTea6 1.11pre to java version "1.7.0_01" But nothing happens needer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after a while, and by using the IRC #apache. I couldn't set up this. so I followed the steps to install the plugin on Eclipse: http://directory.apache.org/studio/installation-in-eclipse.html

This works for me.

But I had to change the java, like @fossfreedom told me, that was a big step forward.